# Rails: storing datatype in a column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Im working on a database table that consists of two columns - one for all the values I'd like to store *converted to `string`s*. And as for the other one, I'd like to store their original datatypes.

I understand that I can store their types in strings (e.g. "`string`", "`fixnum`" etc). However, when I need to retrieve and process that data later on I'll have to `switch` the types (I'd like to avoid that and to be able to convert the values back to their original types immediately.) Is there any way to store what we get from the `.class` call to a database column? And if so, of what type should the column be?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you storing everything as strings in the first place?

Comment: @muistooshort because I declared that column as a string column. Is there a way to create a column that accepts all datatypes?

Comment: Not really. So why did you create the column as a string? What's the real problem you're trying to solve that makes you think storing everything as strings is a solution?

Comment: @muistooshort I created a column of strings because all primitive types can be represented by strings. Both numbers and booleans can be represented by strings. If this is not how data with multiple potential types should be stored please do advise, I'm all ears.

Comment: @muistooshort An applicable situation for my problem would be accepting an `NSDictionary` from iOS / OSX. The keys and values can be of any type and don't have to be consistent. My database needs to handle that.

Comment: It sounds like you are attempting to implement a variant type field. This isn't easy to do I'm afraid. You can store the `regtype` and the `text` or `bytea` of the `type_out` or `type_send` function for that type, but you'd be much better off storing something like `jsonb` scalars.

Comment: I'm with @CraigRinger here, `jsonb` would probably be the easiest fit to your data and Rails4.

Comment: @muistooshort @craig-ringer thanks, I'll look into that. How do you feel about Ryan's suggestion of using `.constantize`? It does look easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [constantize](http://apidock.com/rails/String/constantize) method. It takes a string and tries to convert it to a constant name:

```
"String".constantize   #becomes String
```

Now, the string has to be correctly capitalized for it to work. And if something is wrong, it throws an error. Use [safe_constantize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/safe_constantize) to make it return `nil` when it fails.